# Find the number of functions $f : [\![1,n]\!] \to [\![0,n]\!]$ such that $\forall k \in [\![1,n]\!], \exists k' \in \Bbb N, f^{k'}(k)=0 $.

Tags: combinatorics

> Find the number of functions $f : [\![1,n]\!] \to [\![0,n]\!]$ such that $\forall k \in [\![1,n]\!], \exists k' \in \Bbb N, f^{k'}(k)=0$.

Of course here $f^{k'}(k)=f(f(\cdots(k)\cdots))$.

I've studied the cases $n=1$ ($f=0$ is the only solution) and $n=2$ ($3$ solutions). I had the feeling that there could be something related to disjoint cycles but this is not the case in general (if we take $f : (1,2,3) \mapsto (2,0,2)$ we have $f=(1 \to 2 \to 0)(3 \to 2 \to 0)$).

Comment: Hint: Consider the graph whose vertices are $[\![0,n]\!]$ with an edge from $i$ to $j$ if $f(i)=j$. What kind of graph is this? How do you count graphs of this kind?

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thanks for your hint but I don't have any background in graph theory sorry... But I see that we can have $2 \to 3 \to 1 \to 0$ or $1 \to 3 \to 4 (\uparrow 0) \leftarrow 5 \leftarrow 2$.

Comment: I have computed a few values up to $n=8$: $1, 3, 10, 65, 496, 3877, 36772, 414969$ (program can be run [here](https://onlinegdb.com/S1aIUciTw)).

Comment: @BillyJoe How you got those? the third one should not be $16$?

Comment: @Michelle: A generalization of your problem is treated in [this PDF](http://capone.mtsu.edu/dwalsh/acyclic/ACYCNT3.pdf); specifically, you want the case of Theorem $1$ with $m=1$. There is some use of the language of trees, but the actual argument uses only fairly straightforward combinatorial calculation.

Comment: @Phicar I think it should be correct, because I have made cases $n=3$ and $n=4$ manually too, anyway I could have made a mistake. I will check again. The program enumerates all possible functions.

Comment: For $n=3$: there are 6 of the form $a \mapsto b \mapsto c \mapsto 0$; 6 of the form $a \mapsto b \mapsto 0, c \mapsto 0$; 3 of the form $a \mapsto b \mapsto 0, c \mapsto b$; and 1 of the form $1 \mapsto 0, 2 \mapsto 0, 3 \mapsto 0$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for your answer but I wonder if there isn't a way to get the result "by hand"...

Comment: @Phicar, Daniel Schepler, yes I made a mistake; canceled one line of code [here](https://onlinegdb.com/BylQM6j6D) and now getting $(n+1)^{n-1}$ obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation of "disjoint cycles" are essentially paths that go from non-accessed nodes (the elements that are not in the image of your function) all the way down to $0.$ Show that these are, pictorially, rooted trees in the sense that there is a root(the number that goes to $0$) and there can not be cycles, otherwise, the elements in those cycles never reach $0$.
 This means that [Cayley's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula) applies and there are $(n+1)^{n-1}$ of such functions. Convince yourself by drawing in this pictorial form the functions you got for $n=3.$ Notice that the $n+1$ comes from placing $0$ as the root of this tree (this is probably what Mike's hint was about).