# Counting the number of good functions

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Hy, happy new year everyone.

I have been stuck on the following problem for a while now, so I am posting it here in other to discuss it.

A function $g: [[1,n]] \to [[0,n]]$ is called **good** if :

$$\forall j \in[[1,n]] , \exists i~ \text{integer} \geq 0 , g^{i} (j)=0 $$

where $g^{i}=g\circ \dots \circ g ~~(i ~~\text{times})$

How many  such **good** functions  there is?

Comment: what does the double bracket `[[` mean? is that set a natural numbers less than or equal to n?

Comment: Yes exactly @AvenDesta , $[[l,m]]=\{l,l+1,...,m\}$

Comment: Note that, if $g^{i_0}(j_0) = 0$, $g^{i_1}(j_1) = 0$, $g^{i_2}(j_2) = 0$, ... Then take $i = LCM(i_0, i_1, i_2, ...)$ and $g^{i}(j)=0$ for all $j$

Comment: Where is this question coming from? It's not new...

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3968205

Comment: @MikeEarnest yes its duplicate but I don't think it is answered there

Comment: @AvenDesta from this pdf http://capone.mtsu.edu/dwalsh/acyclic/ACYCNT3.pdf the answer should be $(n+1)^{n-1}$ but it uses graph theory.  If we follow your constatation of taking $i=LCM(i_{0},i_{1},i_{2},...)$ I don't see how we can count all the functions from it

Comment: @uvw its just a hint that could help

Comment: Here's how I approached this problem. Let $A_n,B_m$ be two disjoint sets with respective sizes $n,m\in \mathbb{N}$. Take $a(m,n)$ to be the number of functions $f:A_n \longrightarrow A_n \cup B_m$ with the following property: $$\forall a \in A_n, \text{ } \exists i\geq 0 \text{ such that } f^{i}(a)\in B_m$$ You're looking to compute $a(1,n)$. It turns out that $$a(m,n)=m^n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}m^k{n \choose k}a(k,n-k)$$ Maybe you can use this formula to isolate $a(1,n)$.

Comment: Nice idea I thought about something like this too, how did you justify the formula? the $m^{n}$ represent the case mapping $n$ elements with a set of $m$ element, but the $m^{k} \binom{n}{k} a(k,n-k)$ correspond to taking $k$ elements from $A_{n}$ forcing $f(x)\in B_{m}$ then extending with a function from $A_{n-k} \to A_{n-k} \cup B_{k}$ ? @MatthewPilling

Comment: I forced *exactly* $k$ elements of $A_n$ to get mapped into $B_m$ while the forcing remaining $n-k$ elements to get mapped back into $A_n$. To ensure that all of these $n-k$ elements eventually get mapped into $B_m$ you need to make sure that all $n-k$ of these elements are mapped into the original $k$ elements that you mapped into $B_m$. There are $a(k,n-k)$ such assignments.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_n,B_m$ be two disjoint sets of size $n,m\in \mathbb{N}$.

Take $a(m,n)$ as the number of functions $f:A_n\rightarrow A_n \cup B_m$ satisfying the following condition: $$\forall a\in A_n \text{  } \exists i\geq 0 \text{ such that } f^i(a)\in B_m$$ You're looking to compute $a(1,n)$. Evidently $a(m,1)=m$ and $$a(m,n)=m^n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}m^k {n \choose k}a(k,n-k)$$ It's easily shown that $$a(n,m)=m(m+n)^{n-1}$$ [solves](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mu08zgtj8k) this relation. Taking $m=1$ gives $a(1,n)=(n+1)^{n-1}$ as required.

Comment: Amazing!  we still have to prove the uniqueness of the solution

Comment: lol maybe someone else can help you with the uniqueness part. I totally found this solution by working backwards :-/. I'm glad I was able to find a formula for $a(m,n)$ though! I don't know much about solving equations like these.

Comment: I was going to ask a question on this forum about the solution to this kind of difference equation. I'm still considering it. Honestly I wouldn't have found this formula if I didn't know that $a(1,n)=(n+1)^{n-1}$

Comment: I think we can prove the uniqueness using strong induction on $l=m+n$. But sure I encourage you to open the topic, maybe there is a good way to solve such equation, generating function's maybe. Thank you for your contribution @MatthewPilling

Answer (score 1):

First $g(x)\ne x$ for all $x$, and $g^i(x)=0 \Rightarrow i\leq n$ and there exist a number x such that $g(x)=0$. Let $k_j$ denote number of numbers $x$ s.t. $g^j(x)=0$. So to construct such function, we first select $k_1$ numbers $x$ and force $g(x)=0$ in $\binom{n}{k_1}$ modes. Then we choose $k_2$ numbers and force $g(x)\in g^{-1}(0)$ in $\binom{n-k_1}{k_2}\times k_1^{k_2}$ modes and so on... . Finally the number of functions is:
$$\sum_{k_1\geq 1, k_j\geq0 , j=2,3,\cdots n}\binom{n}{k_1}\times \binom{n-k_1}{k_2}\times k_1^{k_2}\times \binom{n-k_1-k_2}{k_3}\times k_2^{k_3}\cdots \binom{n-k_1-k_2-\cdots k_{n-1}}{k_n}\times k_{n-1}^{k_n}=\sum_{k_1\geq 1, k_j\geq0 , j=2,3,\cdots n}\binom{n}{k_1,k_2,\cdots ,k_{n}}\times  k_1^{k_2}\times k_2^{k_3}\cdots \times k_{n-1}^{k_n}$$

Comment: Thanks @nima for your proposition, from this pdf http://capone.mtsu.edu/dwalsh/acyclic/ACYCNT3.pdf the answer should be $(n+1)^{n-1}$ can we simplify your last sum ?